# Does Windows cache file property settings based on filename

Tags: windows, compatibility, cache

It looks to me that Windows 10 caches file property settings.

I have an App installed with a file called bob.exe. I manually change some properties in settings by right clicking the file and properties. More specifically I changed Compatibility->Compatibility mode->Run this program in Compatibility mode for Windows 7. Then I uninstall the App and downgrade to an elder version. After the old version finishes its installation, I check the property of the same file, bob.exe (technically speaking it's a different file), it still holds the same settings.

So am I right to assume Windows cache file property settings based on filenames for the same App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro compatibility settings, it's based on the Path + Filename.

You can see the entries in your registry by looking in

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers`

So if you reinstalled the same program, but to a different folder, the settings wouldn't stick.

Comment: I see compatibility is cached. What about other settings, like Disable display scaling on high DPI settings?

Comment: It's not "cached", its simply a saved preference.  As for the Display Scaling option, that's also on the Compatibility tab, and as such is also stored in that same registry key. :)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to be consistent. My file settings says it's set to disable Scaling but there is nothing in the same registry. The registry only mentions WIN7RTM. Does WIN7RTM automatically disable scaling?